# Dismissing dialog and showing new one shortly shows underlying fragment before opening new dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogfragment

I currently have one fragment that shows dialogfragment, and when I press the button on dialogfragment, I want to show another dialogfragment. In my first dialog fragment I have following method:

```
 fun showSecondDialog() {
    dismiss()
    SecondDialog().showDialog(targetFragment!!)
}
```

**showDialog()** looks like this:

```
    fun showDialog(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentManager = fragment.fragmentManager
    val ft = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
    val prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(getName())
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev)
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null)

    setTargetFragment(fragment, 0)
    show(ft, getName())
}
```

The problem is, that dismissing dialog works immediately, but before the new dialog is shown there is a gap, where my underlying fragment is fully visible and this causes an undesirable flicker.

How to show second dialog immediately, or how to know when it's opened, so I could close the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also having this same problem, but you can try a workaround like this if it works according to your requirement :

```
fun showSecondDialog() {

    SecondDialog().showDialog(targetFragment!!)

    Handler().postDelayed({ dismiss() }, 1000)

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work as dismiss() dismisses both of my dialogs

Comment: I think it is not possible to dismiss both of your dialogs, just verify your function is calling twice?

Comment: dismiss() method internally calls this.getFragmentManager().popBackStack(this.mBackStackId, 1); which clears all other fragments added after the original fragment which is being dismissed.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that my showDialog uses show(fragmentTransaction, TAG) instead of show(fragmentManager, TAG). Switching to second option helped, and your suggestion is then a viable option. Even though I would use runnable which should be executed after second dialog is shown, not random 1000 ms

Comment: Actually it's not because I used show(fragmentTransaction, TAG), but because I used ft.addToBackStack(null) which somehow caused this effect.

Answer (score -1):

Google recommends all the fragment inflate, replace, dismiss...should be done in the parent activity and no fragment should know anything about any other fragment. That way fragments can be reused like they were initially designed to.

Comment: If I move the code to activity, I still have the same issue